WP Query get posts + show FIRST posts with meta_key (sort by rand) THEN show other posts with no meta_key (sort by date)
I'm trying to:

get all published posts
show FIRST the ones that have the "push_featured" meta key
then show the rest of the posts which don't have the "push_featured" meta key
the ones that HAVE the meta key must be sorted by RAND
other posts must be sorted by DATE desc

here is the query I have:
$args = array(
   'posts_per_page'      => '12',
   'post_type'           => 'place',
   'paged' => $paged,
   'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
   'post_status'         => 'publish',
   'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array( 
            'key'     => 'push_featured',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'push_featured',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        )   
   ),
   'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num rand',
   'order'      => 'desc',
);

P.S. push_featured meta value is in 2024-07-31 13:06:39 format
The current query works with almost all the points I wrote, beside it's RANDomizing ALL the posts, and not only the ones that have the "push_featured" meta key...
Can someone give me a hand on this please?
